# GridView on my GameView (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, gridview, grid, surfaceview, tetris

I have the following problem.

I am trying to code a Tetris Game for Android. Therefore I need to put a Grid on the GameView (a self coded class, which extends the SurfaceVieW).

Unfortunately I do not know how to draw the Grid on the GameView.

I already implemented a Grid class, which sets the width and height of the rows and columns.

My Grid Class

```
    package com.example.tetris;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.widget.GridView;

    public class Grid extends GridView
{
    private int rowsWidth;
    private int columnsHeight;
    private int rowsNum;
    private int columnsNum;
    private Paint gridcolor;
    private GameView gameview;

    public Grid(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void drawGrid(GameView gameview)
    {
        this.gameview = gameview;

        rowsWidth = gameview.getWidth() / 10;

        rowsNum = gameview.getWidth() / rowsWidth;

        columnsHeight = gameview.getHeight()/rowsWidth;

        columnsNum = gameview.getHeight() / columnsHeight;

        setHorizontalSpacing(1);

        setColumnWidth(rowsWidth);
        setNumColumns(columnsNum);
    }


}
```

My GameView Class

```
    package com.example.tetris;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    private Tetriminos[] tetriminos[];

    private GridView grid;

    public GameView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        final GameLoopThread gameloop = new GameLoopThread(this); // warum er final erzwingt, ka

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                gameloop.setRunning(true);
                gameloop.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameloop.setRunning(false);
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawBorders(canvas);
        // grid.drawGrid(this);

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        return false;

    }

    public void drawBorders(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int borderwidth = 10;
        int screenWidth = getWidth();
        int screenHeight = getHeight();
        Paint bordercolor = new Paint();
        bordercolor.setARGB(255, 236, 27, 36);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, borderwidth, getHeight(), bordercolor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, getHeight()-borderwidth, getWidth(), getHeight(), bordercolor);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth()-borderwidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), bordercolor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), borderwidth, bordercolor);
    }

}
```